# Multiple keywords low search

Tags: low-search

I have just purchased Low Search.

Is it possible to perform multiple keyword searches like the following:

Holiday, Cyprus

This does not return the same results as if I searching for the following individually:

Holiday

or

Cyprus

What I would expect is results based on keyword Holiday and ALSO keyword Cyprus but this is not the case.

A heads up on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Low Search you can use multiple keywords. Here are [the docs on the Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords).

Specifically, check out the `search_mode`. By default, this is set to *All*, meaning searching for "holiday cyprus" will return entries that contain both "holiday" *and* "cyprus". You can change that to *Any*, which will return entries that contain either "holiday" *or* "cyprus" (or both).

If you're getting unexpected results, submit a ticket in [the official Low Search support forums](https://getsatisfaction.com/low).

Comment: Hi Low. I have it configured this way using search_mode="all" and I do get unexpected results. I am just getting starting out with it, so it could well be me. I will submit a support. Thanks ;).